How to validate chunking in Llama index after implementation
I am working on building RAG application using Llama index. I have used few of the chunking strategies like SentenceSplitter , SentenceWindowNodeParser and HierarchicalNodeParser. However, i am not able to validate if the chunking happened correctly. Below is an example of my code:
documents= SimpleDirectoryReader(file_path).load_data()

hierarchical_chunking = HierarchicalNodeParser.from_defaults(chunk_sizes=[750,512,256])

pipeline = IngestionPipeline(transformation = [hierarchical_chunking],
                             docstore = SimpleDocumentStore(),)

nodes = pipeline.run(documents=documents, show_progress = False)

no of pages in my pdf is 4, and number of nodes generated is 7. I want to understand how hierarchical chunking is done and I want to validate it.I tried with :
nodes[0].get_info
nodes[0].node_info

but i am not able to see, the chunk size i provided in hierachicalnodeparser.
